# Forward event logs to Sentinel using Azure Monitor Agent (AMA)

Tags: azure, azure-sentinel

We are implementing Sentinel and we want to forward to it the Security Events log, Application Log, and Others Custom event log. For the Security, Events log there is a connector who can forward it to Sentinel, but for the other event log how can I forward it using the Azure Monitor Agent?

Our servers are Windows server 2019 with Azure Monitor Agent onboarded Arc-enabled (on-premises)

[image: This is the connector used]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a [Data Collection Rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/data-collection-rule-overview) to get your other data to the Log Analytics Workspace that Sentinel is attached to.  That is all the **Windows Security Events via AMA** connector you referenced in your question is doing.  The other things you get from a built-in connector, you will need to create on your own.  These include workbooks and analytics rules.

### Considerations

Just be conscious of the fact that *if* you are sending data to Sentinel, and you are not using any analytics rules, you are wasting money.  Sentinel is a Security Event and Incident Management (SEIM) and you will pay extra (on top of the LogA costs) for alerting and automation.  You are better off sending data that has no alerting value to a separate LogA workspace.  You can then do a [cross-workspace query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/cross-workspace-query) to hunt on that dataset.

#### Best Practices

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/billing-reduce-costs#separate-non-security-data-in-a-different-workspace